# Get Sendgrid Activity into my application

Tags: php, mysql, sendgrid, database-administration, sendgrid-api-v3

I am working in an application where Sendgrid is integrated for email magazine. Its working fine but we are stuck with one big issue.

EVENT LOG

Sendgrid gives Activity section which is incredibly useful but no API to fetch data from it.

Tried a lot of ways to get it but the only solution got is to have a web hook and save the events in my own database.
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Track/Collecting_Data/can_i_download_a_list_of_click_and_or_open_events.html

After not having any other choice I created an endpoint in my application which receive the posted events and saving into the database.

Now the issue is the application have thousands of subscribers(more than 60K and growing) and if I receive the events(requests, opened, clicked, differed) into my application, the traffic is going out of control and memory gets full.

60K Users X 4(or 5) Events(per user) = 300K records.

Every week 3 magazine so 300K records X 3 = 900K record in a week

Recent issue : ibdata1 file became 98GB for my 1TB server which pull down the website.

Where I am doing wrong? Is it in mysql configuration or architectural issue?

Comment: How are you storing the events data? If you're [reserving fixed space for null fields](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109210/does-an-empty-column-value-occupy-same-storage-space-as-a-filled-column-value) in your db, you may want to check that.

Comment: I was saving the data in my own database but it turns out taking a lot of bandwidth.